# Configuring JWT Token Validations Parameter cannot be set in ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have a scenario in which I need to set the clock skew for JWT bearer tokens. but whatever I do, the code ignores my settings.

I have tried configuring it in multiple different sections of the Dependency Injection file in the Infrastructure Layer, but it ignores all of them.

I have this at the moment:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
  {
     options.IssuerUri = configuration.GetSection("MyCurrentDomainName")?.Value;
     options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(999);
     options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;

  }).AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();


services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(configuration =>
{
    configuration.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9875664);
});

services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor
    .Singleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureBearerOptions>());

Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();


services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor
   .Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>());
```

The code ignores my configurations and sets the clock skew to its default 5 minutes.

In the last line of the above code, I have a PostConfigurationOption, and I have set the clock skew there as well, it runs the code, but when the WebUI layer calls for the authentication, the clock skew will default to 5 minutes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
  {
     options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(999);
  });
```

If you're using Jwt token, why setting cookie lifetime ?

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(configuration =>
{
    configuration.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9875664);
});
```

`JwtBearerOptions` got registered in the app service but internally. Identity server doens't make use of this.

Identity server internally make use of table `Clients` on the server to skew the clock for each client that we register. The time specified by corresponding columns `IdentityTokenLifetime, AccessTokenLifetime, AuthorizationCodeLifetime, ConsentLifetime, AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime, SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime`, modify them as you need.

**UPDATE**

The template still make use of `IdentityServer4`, it doesn't make it own magic. And that's what happen in the template.

In Startup, service called `AddInfrastructure`. which let the app to use In-memory database (as default config on appSettings), furthur more, IdentityServer took the `IdentityServerSPA` option on `appSettings` as it's profile. which will get config at `.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()`.

Since it's a pre-config profile, you cannot mess with it.

For the most clearly instruction, use localdb sql server. I think the way to do that is clear enougn in `DependencyInjection` file on `Infrastructure` layer. Then we'll see the table magically appear on sql.

And if it's just a simple demo, try this:

```
// Modify this block code in DependencyInjection file, Infrastructure layer
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(cfg =>
                {
                    var defaultClient = cfg.Clients["CleanArchitecture.WebUI"];
                    defaultClient.AccessTokenLifetime = 3600; // 3600s
                });
```

And other lifetime for each kind of token per client can be configure as well.

Comment: I am using Jason Taylor's Clean Architecture template: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture. There is no Clients table or an appsettings file that configures the clients. How can I find where these settings are coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the response by the way

Comment: It doens't matter, the template make use of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer`, which have `IdentityServer4` as its dependency... and believe me, it does use the `Clients` table. But that's quite a bad luck at your circumstance... please take a look at my updated section.